# Return Current Object Through Static method

Tags: php

i want to return the current object of a class. As $this variable refers to current object of   that class but when i return this  i get an error.

here is my code

```
class Test{
    $name;
    public static function getobj($n){ 
        $this->name; return $this; 
    }
}
$obj= Test::getobj("doc");
```

Comment: Use the Singleton pattern?

Comment: Hate to say this, but your code doesn't compile.

Comment: *"when i return this i get an error"* - Which is?

Comment: If you need to get object of the class, it's simple $obj = new Test();

Comment: @Fred-ii- most probably `using $this in static context`

Comment: @Twisted1919 Indeed. However, OP should've included the actual error message being `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$name' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in...` ;) Dropping code and telling us "here's my code" doesn't wash well.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, you are perfectly right :)

Comment: @Twisted1919 OP states: *"it is not working still getting the same error"* in Jack's answer. OP really should give more detail in the question as to what he/she is doing; meaning how is using it. I don't touch questions like these. ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- i see, i honestly thought you just asked as an info, a bit naive i'd say :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I want to pass a resultset to a static function of a class , the static function converts the resultset into object and return that  object

Answer (score 6):

You can't use `$this` inside a static method, so you'd have to create an instance of the class and then return that:

```
class Test
{
    public $name;

    public static function getobj($n)
    {
        $o = new self;
        $o->name = $n;

        return $o;
    }
}

$obj = Test::getobj("doc"); // $obj->name == "doc"
```

Comment: @arifhussainshigri oh oops, typo =p

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't do this. Static methods exist *without an instance of the class*. You can call a static method without having any instances in existence at all. There isn't a `$this` because there isn't an instance. If you want one then you'll need to create one:

```
$obj = new Test();
```

What you probably want to do is something like this:

```
class Test
{
    private $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

Now you can create an instance of the class as follows:

```
$obj = new Test('doc');
```

---

Some comments are referring to something called a *Singleton pattern*. You can use this if you know you'll only ever want to have one instance of a class in existence. It works by storing that instance in a static variable on the class:

```
class A()
{
    /**
     * The instance itself
     * @var A
     */
    private static $instance;

    /**
     * Constructor. Private so nobody outside the class can call it.
     */
    private function __construct() { };

    /**
     * Returns the instance of the class.
     * @return A
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        // Create it if it doesn't exist.
        if (!self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new A();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static ?Logger $instance = null;


public static function getInstance(): Logger
{
    if (static::$instance === null) {
        static::$instance = new static();
    }

    return static::$instance;
}
```